# Class property as instance of another class VBA

Tags: excel, vba, class, properties

Is there a way that I can set a class property to be an instance of another class? So far I can access every property from my DealStatCls, but I can't access my MainCls in the module. I assume my mistake is somewhere in setting the properties.

This would be my MainCls

```
Private pDealStatus As DealStatCls

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     Set pDealStatus = New DealStatCls
    End Sub

    Property Let DealStatus(value As DealStatCls)
        pDealStatus = value
    End Property
    Property Get DealStatus() As DealStatCls
        DealStatus = pDealStatus
    End Property
```

This would be my DealStatCls

```
Private pActive As Integer

Public Property Let Active(value As Integer)
    If IsEmpty(pActive) Then
        pActive = value
    Else
        pActive = pActive + value
    End If
End Property
Public Property Get Active() As Integer
    Active = pActive
End Property
```

Comment: One obvious issue:  you need to use `Property Set` for DealStatus.

Comment: Yup that fixed it. Way simpler than what I thought!

Comment: By the way, `IsEmpty()` only works with Variant data-type. Integer types default to zero, so you can remove the `If` statement and simply sum the values.

Comment: Even better. Thanks !